# "Vector Subscript Out of Range" using std::vector as the value in an std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have the following code, which is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

```
std::vector<GLuint> testVector = { 6, 7, 8 };
std::map<std::pair<GLfloat, GLfloat>, std::vector<GLuint>> testMap;
testMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1.0f,1.0f), testVector));

std::vector <GLuint> retrievalVector =
                                  testMap.find(std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f))->second;

std::cout << "Retrieval Vector: " << retrievalVector[0] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[1] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[2] << std::endl;

retrievalVector.push_back(9);

std::cout << "Retrieval Vector: " << retrievalVector[0] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[1] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[2] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[3] << std::endl;

testMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f), retrievalVector));
retrievalVector = testMap.find(std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f))->second;

std::cout << "Retrieval Vector: " << retrievalVector[0] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[1] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[2] << "\t" 
                                  << retrievalVector[3] << std::endl;
```

Basically, I insert a vector of integers into a map using coordinates as a key. I retrieve the same vector and find that the contents were stored successfully. I then add another integer to the vector and reinsert it in the same place. Retrieving it once more and attempting to print the vector's contents (the last cout) leads to an out of range access.

Can someone who is more knowledgeable explain why this occurs?

Comment: Floats are notoriously finnicky and you probably don't want to use them for keys where exact matches are necessary. Does this work with `int` in place of `GLfloat`? Also if you're looking to manipulate `retrievalVector` you might want to declare that as a reference, not a copy.

Comment: Using floats as the key of a map is going to cause you all sorts of grief in the future unless you are *very* careful with your numerical analysis.  Can't you use scaled integers instead?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is exactly as expected. [According to the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

You already have a `std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f)` in there, so your return value should be:

> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.

If you check `testMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f), retrievalVector)).second` it should be `false`, so there is still a three-element array there, not the four-element one you hoped had been added, therefore the program crashes on trying to access `retrievalVector[3]`.

By the way, C++17 has an [`insert_or_assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) function that will do what you hoped `insert()` would do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your second `insert` fails, as you already have a value at that position. If you want to modify the value, you have to do something like `testMap[std::make_pair(1.0f, 1.0f)] = retrievalVector;`.